# How to make a single method for calling api and pass the respective pojo class to retrofit call?

Tags: android, retrofit2

How to make a single method for calling api and pass the respective pojo class to retrofit call?

Retrofit2 callback

But for every other request i need to make different pojo and write same code for retrofit call.I want to make a single method for calling api and pass the respective pojo class to retrofit call

Comment: if it's the same GET call, but different queries, then just use the @QueryMap annotation. if it's different, then you are out of luck. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-add-multiple-query-parameter-with-querymap

Comment: I want a complete demo.Please help me.